# I have to display image and data from xml, how can I do it in php?

Tags: php, xml

Each time it loops, the text that it shows only the `Product_URL`. I really confuse how to solve this problem. I guess there is something wrong with the loop.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Display main Image</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <table>
        <tr>
         <th>Thumbnail Image</th>
         <th>Product Name</th>
         <th>Product Description</th>
         <th>Price</th>
         <th>Weight</th>
         <th>Avail</th>
         <th>Product URL</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <?php
            $doc = new DOMDocument;

            $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;           
            $doc->Load('xml_feeds7.xml');
            $xpath = new DOMXPath($doc);

            $listquery = array('//item/thumbnail_url', '//item/productname', '//item/productdesciption', '//item/price', '//item/weight', '//item/avail', '//item/product_url');

            foreach ($listquery as $queries) {
             $entries = $xpath->query($queries);
             foreach ($entries as $entry) { ?>
        <tr>
        <td>
            <img src="<?php echo $entry->nodeValue; ?>" width="100px" height="100px">
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo "$entry->nodeValue"; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo "$entry->nodeValue"; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php 
            $price_value = $entry->nodeValue;
            echo str_replace($price_value, ".00", "");
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
        <?php 
            $weight_value = $entry->nodeValue;
            echo str_replace($weight_value, ".00", "");
            ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo "$entry->nodeValue"; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo "$entry->nodeValue"; ?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo "$entry->nodeValue"; ?>
        </td>
        </tr>
    }

   }
        </tr>
       </table>
       </body>
  </html>
```

The table should be displaying:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Thumbnail | Product Name | Description | Price | Weight | Avail | Product_URL |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You are  echoing only this in all the tds - <?php echo "$entry->nodeValue"; ?> You have to echo different properties of the $entry object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xpath can return scalar values (strings and numbers) directly, but you have to do the typecast in the Expression and use `DOMxpath::evaluate()`.

You should iterate the items and then use the item as a context for the detail data expressions. Building separate lists can result in invalid data (if an element in on of the items is missing).

Last you can use DOM methods to create the HTML table. That way it will take care of escaping and closing the tags.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<items>
  <item>
    <thumbnail_url>image.png</thumbnail_url>
    <productname>A name</productname>
    <productdescription>Some text</productdescription>
    <price currency="USD">42.21</price>
    <weight unit="g">23</weight>
    <avail>10</avail>
    <product_url>page.html</product_url>
  </item>
</items>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument;
$document->preserveWhiteSpace = false;           
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($document);

$fields = [
  'Thumbnail' => 'string(thumbnail_url)',
  'Product Name' => 'string(productname)',
  'Description' => 'string(productdescription)',
  'Price' => 'number(price)',
  'Weight' => 'number(weight)',
  'Availability' => 'string(avail)',
  'Product_URL' => 'string(product_url)'
];

$html = new DOMDocument();
$table = $html->appendChild($html->createElement('table'));
$row = $table->appendChild($html->createElement('tr'));

// add table header cells
foreach ($fields as $caption => $expression) {
  $row
    ->appendChild($html->createElement('th'))
    ->appendChild($html->createTextNode($caption));  
}

// iterate the items in the XML
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('//item') as $item) {
  // add a new table row
  $row = $table->appendChild($html->createElement('tr'));
  // iterate the field definitions
  foreach ($fields as $caption => $expression) {
    // fetch the value using the expression in the item context
    $value = $xpath->evaluate($expression, $item);
    switch ($caption) {
    case 'Thumbnail':
      // special handling for the thumbnail field
      $image = $row
        ->appendChild($html->createElement('td'))
        ->appendChild($html->createElement('img'));
      $image->setAttribute('src', $value);
      break;
    case 'Price':
    case 'Weight':
      // number format for price and weight values
      $row
        ->appendChild($html->createElement('td'))
        ->appendChild(
          $html->createTextNode(
            number_format($value, 2, '.')
          )
      );  
      break;
    default:
      $row
        ->appendChild($html->createElement('td'))
        ->appendChild($html->createTextNode($value));  
    }
  }
}

$html->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $html->saveHtml();
```

Output:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>Thumbnail</th>
<th>Product Name</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Weight</th>
<th>Availability</th>
<th>Product_URL</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td><img src="image.png"></td>
<td>A name</td>
<td>Some text</td>
<td>42.21</td>
<td>23.00</td>
<td>10</td>
<td>page.html</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Holy moly! Thanks for the answer, it works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

I've changed it to use SimpleXML as this is a fairly simple data structure - but this fetches each `<item>` and then displays the values from there.  I've only done this with a few values, but hopefully this shows the idea...

```
$doc = simplexml_load_file('xml_feeds7.xml');
foreach ( $doc->xpath("//item") as $item )  {
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td><img src=\"{$item->thumbnail_url}\" width=\"100px\" height=\"100px\"></td>";
    echo "<td>{$item->productname}</td>";
    echo "<td>{$item->productdesciption}</td>";

    // Other fields...

    $price_value = str_replace(".00", "",(string)$item->price);
    echo "<td>{$price_value}</td>";

    // Other fields...

    echo "</tr>";
}
```

Rather than use XPath for each value, it uses `$item->elementName`, so `$item->productname` is the productname. A much simpler way of referring to each field.
Note that with the price field, as you are processing it further - you have to cast it to a string to ensure it will process correctly.

Update:
If you need to access data in a namespace in SimpleXML, you can use XPath, or in this case there is a simple (bit roundabout way).  Using the `->children()` method you can pass the namespace of the elements you want, this will then give you a new SimpleXMLElement with all the elements for that namespace.

```
$extraData = $item->children('g',true);
echo "<td>{$extraData->productname}</td>";
```

Now - `$extraData` will have any element with g as the namespace prefix, and they can be referred to in the same way as before, but instead of `$item` you use `$extraData`.

Comment: Hi Nigel thank you for the answer. I have another question, if the tag name is g:productname, how can I write it in the 'echo "<td>{$item->productname}</td>";?

Comment: I've added an extra bit to the answer for that.